# Building a Hashmap of Hashmaps

Tags: powershell, hashmap, hashtable

I don't often ask questions (most times the problem can be solved by some research right?) but I just wanna hear out your opinion as probably there is a better (more efficient way of doing this).

So let's see, the code below works perfectly fine and it serves it's purpose. The result of the code is a hashmap of hashmaps that I need as lookup table for on another work.

Background:

- `$ccDb` is an array consisting of around 200k items, the properties are `companyCd, costCenterNbr, costCenterShortNm, costCenterLongDescr`.
- Each property has to be trimmed (please don't ask me to trim my Db, sadly I can't).
- `costCenterNbr` is contained on `companyCd`, meaning, each `companyCd` can have multiple `costCenterNbr`.
- `companyCd` can contain X amount of `costCenterNbr`.
- `costCenterNbr` have unique value, same for `companyCd`.
- `costCenterShortNm` and `costCenterLongDescr` are correlated with `costCenterNbr`

The Issue:

This map has to be constructed on each run of my script because the information is taken from SQL tables (which changes all the time). Building this map takes around 15 minutes (on a pretty good server, 2CPUs 12Cores).

The question:

Do you see a way this code could be improved for a faster / more efficient execution?

```
$ccMap=@{}

foreach($line in $ccDb)
{
    $companyCd=$line.companyCd.trim()
    $costCenterNbr=$line.costCenterNbr.trim()
    $costCenterShortNm=$line.CostCenterShortNm.trim()
    $costCenterLongDescr=$line.CostCenterLongDescr.trim()
    
    $coceMap=@{
        $costCenterNbr=@{
            shortDesc=$costCenterShortNm
            longDesc=$costCenterLongDescr
        }
    }
    
    if($ccMap.ContainsKey($companyCd))
    {
        $ccMap[$companyCd]+=$coceMap
    }
    else
    {
        $ccMap.Add($companyCd,$coceMap)
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for the long explanation, but I feel like it's better to give the most information up front. Any help is very much appreciated. In addition, I understand PowerShell is a pretty awful language for what I'm doing and C# would be probably a lot more efficient but it is what it is.

Edit: Adding measurements for reference.

[image: measure1]

[image: measure2]

Edit:

Thanks a lot @Mathias R. Jessen, here are the measure results of his code. Excellent code.

[image]

Comment: You might look at Group-Object with the -AsHashTable switch.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing classic data management.  A classic Data Base Management System  (DBMS) is awfully good for this sort of thing.  Your data apparently originated from SQL, so I assume it's coming out of a DBMS.  Why aren't you doing the data transformation and reduction in SQL, and then passing the reduced data out to Powershell?

Comment: yup, already did, group-object is much slower.

Comment: Do you have many duplicate `companyCd` values in `$ccDb`? :-)

Comment: @WalterMitty the data is coming from a join of 2 SQL tables, the thing is my knowledge of SQL is not very good compared to my knowledge of PowerShell. Is it possible to get a hashmap of hashmaps out of a SQL query? My question might be dumb, sorry for that.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen There are 839 unique `companyCd`. All properties are unique, there are no duplicates.

Comment: Are you just using an SQL module? You should be able to have the DB trim it for you too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Don't use `+=` in tight loops

Here's your biggest sink:

```
    $ccMap[$companyCd] += $coceMap
```

When you add one hashtable to another using `+` (or `+=` for that matter), PowerShell creates *a whole new hashtable*:

```
# Create two different hashtables
$A = @{ Key1 = 'Value1' }
$B = @{ Key2 = 'Value2' }

# Let's save a second reference to the first table
$remember = $A

# Now let's use += to merge the two:
$A += $B
```

Run this and you'll find `$B` and `$remember` are unchanged, but `$A` has both keys - and must therefore be a new one.

To get around this performance penalty, skip the construction of `$coceMap` completely, and reverse the order (construct hashtable first if not present, then assign):

```
$ccMap=@{}

foreach($line in $ccDb)
{
    $companyCd=$line.companyCd.trim()
    $costCenterNbr=$line.costCenterNbr.trim()
    $costCenterShortNm=$line.CostCenterShortNm.trim()
    $costCenterLongDescr=$line.CostCenterLongDescr.trim()

    # Create new hashtable if none exist, otherwise retrieve the existing one
    if($ccMap.ContainsKey($companyCd))
    {
        $coceMap = $ccMap[$companyCd]
    }
    else
    {
        $coceMap = $ccMap[$companyCd] = @{}
    }
    
    $coceMap[$costCenterNbr] = @{
        shortDesc=$costCenterShortNm
        longDesc=$costCenterLongDescr
    }
}
```

---

### Benchmarking `+=`

Here's a simplified example of the difference against 10000 items with 50 disctinct keys:

```
$data = @(
    1..10000 |Select-Object @{Name='Company';Expression={Get-Random -Maximum 50}},@{Name='CostCenter';Expression={Get-Random}}
)

@(
    Measure-Command {
        $map = @{}

        foreach($line in $data){
            $entry = @{
                $line.CostCenter = @{
                    Value = 123
                }
            }

            if($map.ContainsKey($line.Company)){
                $map[$line.Company] += $entry
            }
            else {
                $map[$line.Company] = $entry
            }
        }
    }

    Measure-Command {
        $map = @{}

        foreach($line in $data){
            if($map.ContainsKey($line.Company)){
                $entry = $map[$line.Company]
            }
            else {
                $entry = $map[$line.Company] = @{}
            }

            $entry[$line.CostCenter] = @{
                Value = 123
            }
        }
    }
) |select TotalMilliseconds
```

Which on my laptop gives:

```
TotalMilliseconds
-----------------
         306.4218
          47.8164
```

---

### How to identify time sinks like this in general?

There are a number of ways to profile the runtime behavior of PowerShell, but here's my personal first choice:

1. Install [`PSProfiler`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSProfiler) (***Disclaimer**: I'm the maintainer of `PSProfiler`*):

   - `Install-Module PSProfiler -Scope CurrentUser`
2. Use `Measure-Script` the same way you would `Measure-Command`:

```
Measure-Script {
    $map = @{}

    foreach($line in $data){
        $entry = @{
            $line.CostCenter = @{
                Value = 123
            }
        }

        if($map.ContainsKey($line.Company)){
            $map[$line.Company] += $entry
        }
        else {
            $map[$line.Company] = $entry
        }
    }
}
```

3. Wait for the code to finish
4. Review the output:

```
    Anonymous ScriptBlock


      Count  Line       Time Taken Statement
      -----  ----       ---------- ---------
          0     1    00:00.0000000 {
          1     2    00:00.0000187     $map = @{}
          0     3    00:00.0000000
          0     4    00:00.0000000     foreach($line in $data){
      10000     5    00:00.0635585         $entry = @{
          0     6    00:00.0000000             $line.CostCenter = @{
          0     7    00:00.0000000                 Value = 123
          0     8    00:00.0000000             }
          0     9    00:00.0000000         }
          0    10    00:00.0000000
          0    11    00:00.0000000         if($map.ContainsKey($line.Company)){
       9950    12    00:00.3965227             $map[$line.Company] += $entry
          0    13    00:00.0000000         }
          0    14    00:00.0000000         else {
         50    15    00:00.0002810             $map[$line.Company] = $entry
          0    16    00:00.0000000         }
          0    17    00:00.0000000     }
          0    18    00:00.0000000 }
```

Observe that line 12 took the up the most total execution time - significantly more than any other:

```
       9950    12    00:00.3965227             $map[$line.Company] += $entry
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Let me check, i'll update soon with measure of time.

Comment: I may be wrong here but this doesn't produce any output `$coceMap = $ccMap.Add($companyCd, @{})`. I'm getting the following exception with this: `System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot index into a null array.`

Comment: Ok well, you're insane. I'm trying to grasp your code but this is so clever. Check out my edit. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @santisq I've added a much simpler example along with how I made the measurement to identify it, maybe it helps you reason about it?

Comment: Great explanation, and for sure will install your module. I understood most of your code except for `$entry = $map[$line.Company] = @{}` which is something I've never seen before. Will need to study it on detail to get a better understanding but i'm super burned out rn :P Thanks again!

Comment: @santisq get some rest, enjoy your weekend ;) It's not as mysterious as it looks, `$A = $B = $C` is the same as `$B = $C; $A = $B` - I was just too lazy to write 2 lines ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

You don't need the `if` \ `else` \ `.add()` statement at all, powershell will add the keys as needed. This should take off the majority of time since you aren't searching your entire table for each entry:

```
$ccMap[$companyCd]+=$coceMap
```

You don't need to set a variable above if you're just using the value once. Just use your `$line`:

```
$coceMap=@{
    $line.costCenterNbr.trim()=@{
        shortDesc = $line.CostCenterShortNm.trim()
        longDesc  = $line.CostCenterLongDescr.trim()
    }
}
```

Comment: "powershell will add the keys as needed." <-- this might affect an even bigger penalty FWIW

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen is correct here, can't tell if this work as it was running for more than 20 minutes so I decided to stop it.