# How do I measure duration (in seconds) for different functions in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, time, duration, stopwatch, measure

I have a powershell script that runs for around 60 seconds . As part of optimization I would like to know which part of the script is taking more time . the script has several functions like making a restcall to a TFS in ADO , validating the content, Publishing etcc..

Even if there is no scope for optimization I would like to provide evidence with duration for each tasks in the script. I did research and found options to use Measure cmd, stopwatch but I am not sure how to use it within the functions. Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: There's [Measure-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Have a look at the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66715584/11954025) by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) for a nice module called PSProfiler that includes a function called `Measure-Script` that I think would help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Daniel kindly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554977/how-do-i-measure-duration-in-seconds-for-different-functions-in-a-powershell-s#comment121159875_68554977), I maintain [a module called PSProfiler](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSProfiler/1.0.3.0) designed to collect line-by-line execution time measurements from an arbitrary script or scriptblock:

```
# Install PSProfiler
Install-Module PSProfiler -Scope CurrentUser

# Import PSProfiler
Import-Module PSProfiler

# Profile sample script
Measure-Script -Name "Arunkumar's script " {
  Start-Sleep 1
  Start-Sleep 2
}
```

For which you'll get output like this:

```
    Anonymous ScriptBlock:
    Arunkumar's script


      Count  Line       Time Taken Statement
      -----  ----       ---------- ---------
          0     1    00:00.0000000 {
          1     2    00:01.0116913   Start-Sleep 1
          1     3    00:02.0037062   Start-Sleep 2
          0     4    00:00.0000000 }
```

The sample script is obviously not that interesting, but as you can see it gives you, for every line:

1. A `Count` - the number of times execution of a statement starting on that particular line occurred
2. Total execution time measured.

This can be useful to hone in on which exact lines/statements you might want to optimize :-)

---

It's worth noting that PSProfiler works by instrumenting the source code, and therefore only measures time taken between statements as they're written in your script.

If you want more granular profiling telemetry at depth, take a look at [Profiler](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Profiler/3.1.1) by [nohwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3065397/nohwnd)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to run the script and measure the duration. I just made one change as below to force the installation. Thanks much.

Install-Module PSProfiler -Force